# Python split dataframe column with pipe

Tags: python, regex, pipe

Suppose I have a pandas data frame df

```
userid      subcategory             timestamp                  smartexpenseid                                         companyid
20648196    SmartExpense Declined   2016-03-06T16:44:55.702Z    11771712||91164585||||                                9797
43124398    SmartExpense Declined   2016-03-06T17:09:06.033Z    11111111|249178181?CARRT?266298850196|93461910||||    63177
76764125    SmartExpense Declined   2016-03-06T19:44:19.078Z    137177|250155900?HOTEL?270593373724|92826286||||      199412
```

---

I want to split the smartexpenseid column into separate columns in the same data frame 11111111|249178181?CARRT?266298850196|93461910|||| -> “CctKey|TripId?SegType?SegId|EreceiptId|PctKey|MeKey|RcKey|CapKey”

Can somebody please suggest a best possible way to do it in Python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
(?<CctKey>\d+)\|(?<TripId>\d*)\??(?<SegType>[^?]*)\??(?<SegId>\d*)\|(?<EreceiptId>\d+)\|(?<PctKey>[^|]*)\|(?<MeKey>[^|]*)\|(?<RcKey>[^|]*)\|(?<CapKey>[^|\n\s]*)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fV5cM3/1)

Remove all group `?<name>` syntax in Python

```
(\d+)\|(\d*)\??([^?]*)\??(\d*)\|(\d+)\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|([^|\n\s]*)
```

Comment: regex = '(?<CctKey>\d+)\|(?<TripId>\d*)\??(?<SegType>[^?]*)\??(?<SegId>\d*)\|(?<EreceiptId>\d+)\|(?<PctKey>[^|]*)\|(?<MeKey>[^|]*)\|(?<RcKey>[^|]*)\|(?<CapKey>[^|\n\s]*)'
df2['smartexpenseid'].str.extract(regex)

Thanks for the answer ! I tried to add it in python and it gave me an error stating only "syntax error"

Comment: Remove all group ?<name> syntax `(\d+)\|(\d*)\??([^?]*)\??(\d*)\|(\d+)\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|([^|\n\s]*) ` https://regex101.com/r/fV5cM3/2

Comment: Thank you so much TIm007. That really helped !